# Visual Studio Source Server with Async/Await method debugging

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, asynchronous, nuget

I have an odd one that I have been working on for two days.

We have a TeamCity/ProGet setup for our internal nuget packages. It got to the point where we needed to debug the nuget packages so I went ahead and enabled source server support. Everything wired up nice and easy and I moved on.

Later in the day I attempted to step into an awaitable method in a nuget package and it stepped right over it (no error or printed output stating the source could not be found).

During my troubleshooting I created a sync wrapper for the method I was trying to step into, republished the nuget package and attempted to step into it which worked without issue.

To rule out the more complex library I created a new nuget package with two methods:

```
    public async Task<bool> MyTestAsync()
    {
        return await Task.FromResult(true);
    }

    public bool MyTest()
    {
        return MyTestAsync().Result;
    }
```

I can step into the sync method everytime without issue but VS 2015 steps over the async method each and every time.

To rule out my box I went to a fresh image and reproduced the test which yielded the same results.

Is there a limitation to source/symbol server debugging that I cannot see to find in a google search? Has anyone else gotten this to work?

Comment: This is easily reproducible as long as you have a nuget, symbol and source server setup. I can get a break point to work if I let the code run through once and walk it back with intellitrace and while historically debugging set a break point in the code I want to debug. On next execution it will stop inside the method instead of stepping over it. I am hoping someone has some insight because not all dev's have 2015 Enterprise so this workaround won't work.

Comment: Further update... If I copy the source in question from the source server into a directory at the root of the symbol path (d:\cachedsymbols in my case), open the source file in the IDE and set a break point in the async method that the IDE will not step into and execute the code again it will break there allowing debugging as desired. Right now the "defect" looks like a Visual Studio one that does not allow source server retrieval (confirmed with Fiddler) for stepping into async methods or moving into the method if the source is already present. It only seems to work if a manual break is set.

Comment: I think this problem is unrelated to symbol servers/source servers, but is a problem with the PDBs generated by MSBuild 14 when compiling in Release mode. I've filed an issue [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/issues/1029).

Answer (score -1):

I ran into a similar issue where I was able to step through synchronous code but not async methods.I also confirmed that the debugger was not attempting to use SRCSRV to resolve source file locations for async code. I turned on Address Level Debugging in the VS general debug settings and that fixed the issue for me.